# How to write an Eclipse component (editor, launcher, ...) that can execute my custom DSL files?

Tags: eclipse, editor, launcher

Let's say I have defined a small little textual DSL and I have an 'interpreter' that will parse and execute commands of a file in that DSL.

What is the best way to start such an interpreter in Eclipse?

For instance, I want to double click on a file and, based on the fact that it has the extension .mydsl, start the interpreter. Another option could be using a launcher with "Run As ...".

So should I look at implementing a ...

- **custom launcher** (extending `org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes`, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLauncherFramework/article.html), or
- **editor**, that is not actually editing the file, but will be called when the file is double clicked (extending `EditorPart`, https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_editor%3F)
- something else?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

For that I would recommend to implement a **custom launcher** to get for free:

- in main toolbar *Run* button with history support
- ability to share launch configuration via version control (in *Common* tab choose *Shared file*)
- [Launch Group](https://youtu.be/Y0-cO9wZj6w?t=20s) support
- etc.

In *Project Explorer*, *Package Explorer*, *Navigator* and similar views a double-click opens a file. In order not to confuse the user you should not change this behavior. But in addition to the custom launcher you could consider to implement an editor with a run button similar to PDE's *[Product Configuration Editor](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/product_editor/overview.htm)* or a view similar to the [Ant view](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-antview.htm) that shows your DSL scripts that can be run on double-click.